# ¿Como ejecutar una consulta n cantidad de veces?

Tags: php, html, sql

Estoy realizando una tabla en html y php, mi problema es que estoy tratando de ejecutar una consulta(`insert`) 'n' cantidad de veces, estoy tratando con un `for`.

Éste es mi código hasta ahora

```
<?php 

    for($ca=1; $ca<25; $ca++){
        $sqlc="insert into riesgos(no_riesgo,unidad_ad,seleccion_ad,descripcion_a,riesgod,nivel_de_dec,seleccion_c,otro,efectos,impacto_i,ocurrencia_i,controles_p,impacto_f,ocurrencia_f,estrategia,descripcion,no_factor,descripcion_f,clasificacion_f,tipo_f,no_control,descripcion_c,tipo_c,documentado,formalizado,aplica,efectivo) values('C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','','','','','','','','','','','','')";
        $res = mysql_query($sqlc,Conectar::con());
    }

?>
```

Para que quede un poco mas claro y la funcionalidad de insertar muchas `'C'`, la `C` significa que voy a combinar las celdas de mi tabla (esto está hecho), **son 25 combinaciones**, y las que no tienen la la `'C'` requiero combinarlas **solo 5 veces**.

¡Ojalá puedan ayudarme!
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Primero le recomiendo en lugar de hacer eso haga un  procedimiento donde reciba todos los datos en formato [JSON](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) ejemplo

```
[{"nombre":"Pedro","apellido":"Fernandez"},{"nombre":"Jacinto","apellido":"Benavente"} ]
```

Luego de esto en el procedimiento que cree en su gestor de BD cree el 
`for`  e inserte todos estos datos. con esto no tendrá que hacer 25 conexiones a la base de datos, tendrá mas control y seguridad en los datos.

Si por el contrario quiere insertar todos los datos así como esta haciendo sencillamente concatene cada uno de los insert

```
 $sqlc .= "insert into riesgos(...)"
```

Con esto solo hará una conexión a la BD y sera mucho mas rápido.

Espero haber ayudado a resolver la duda. BUEN DÍA

Comment: Gracias por el Tip!...